# How do you get all available device densities via android studio?

Tags: android

I did find a lot of code to get current screen density in dpi and scale ratio and etc.

However what I am looking for a way to get a list of all densities that are shown inside the screen zoom view in device settings of a phone -

How do you get all available device densities via android studio?

please see a screenshot for more details on the question:
[image: screenshot]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing different things here. Density it's something tight to the device, in order to support `dp` and `sp` locally (based on screen resolution). Which means just factor to multiply pixels on this device.

You question "*To get a list of all densities that are shown inside the screen zoom view in device settings of a phone*" makes no sense. Since you are asking about some magic list of factors.

Now, to answer question, how to make something similar shown in the screen is pretty easy. You implementation starts with default and correct density supported by this device (as shown on image, we have centered slider), and just applying new factor changes of this density, based on user input from slider. So all your views should be aligned from encapsulated logic with using this changed scale factor (based on initial density of the device).

Comment: okay - is there a way to pull a list of those densities specific to device - that is to clarify my question for anyone who still thinks that is a question about interface design - i couldn't care less of that but what is actually needed is a device specific list of densities that are listed in the screenshot but i am looking for a programmatic way like so maybe "320,480,640,720" - please refer to the density api link: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#DENSITY_DEFAULT

Comment: I don't understand, what you mean by "device specific"? Are you asking about a way to extract all possible density values? Like 320, 640, etc.

Comment: see a screenshot posted above? that is device specific screen zoom levels (in android studio api they are referred as levels of screen densities - you can navigate above link as well to see what is what there) - so each level has its own number whether it is a dpi or a numeric value - long story short - the screenshot shows several levels each has a value - so is there a way to programmatically get that list of values as shown in the screen - nothing else just those 3 values as in the screenshot - that is again a device specific screen - if you open another device's screen zoom levels -

Comment: then you will see 4 or 5 or even 6 levels - so how would one get list of values as noted in previous post - ergo a code that works on any device and pulls a list of screen zoom levels - just screen zoom levels - not the whole list of every possible value of screen densities that have nothing to do with that screen zoom levels as in above screenshot - HTH!

Comment: just so you know - when look at the screenshot i posted above - it shows a scale bar and plus and minus on each side - it does look confusing cause one might think that you can simply drag the handle and leave it either quarter or third way between left and right edges of the scale bar - BUT in fact the handle jumps either to max or to middle or to min points and does not allow to leave the handle between for example max and middle - ergo only 3 levels in that scale bar -

Comment: just trying to clarify to anyone who thinks all density levels can be set via that screen zoom view - nope! only 3 on this particular device - but a different device allows me to pick and set from 6 levels of screen zoom - and one more device allows me to pick and set from 4 levels only - HTH!

Comment: @NashBrooklyn Your question just looks different from image and comments. Again. Above image shows default `scale density`, most suitable for this device. Slider just changes this density in different directions. Why this density slider (aka levels from your comments above) different for different devices? I think, they just have formula for threshold for minimum and max values, based on the device default.

Comment: Smth like: `val minDens = default - (default  * 40%)` `val maxDens = default + (default  * 40%)` `val levels = (maxDens - minDens) / step`. Where step could be 0.2 scaling changes. And in usage for one devices you could have 10 levels, and  4 for another.

Comment: sorry but i still got no straight answer so far - all i want to  know is very simple answer - if no such list available then just so it so that a device will not give you a list of density numbers from the screen zoom view - i know that it can give me a currently selected density from screen zoom view but not other available in that screen densities (keep in mind that i am referring to AVAILABLE densities from that view only and nothing else) -

Comment: @NashBrooklyn Did you read the answer? I said there is no magic list of densities. Just in case you cannot use google https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.